# Krack attack security updates?

Tags: wifi, security

I just read about the Krack attack, which describes a weakness in the WPA2 protocol that impacts almost all devices that use WiFi. 
More info: 
https://www.krackattacks.com/
https://github.com/kristate/krackinfo

How do I know whether ElementaryOS (or Ubuntu LTS) is patched and/or when a patched will be released?

(I'm already using a vpn service to protect myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the update is released: https://twitter.com/pforemski/status/919966850208890880

I did have a update for `wpasupplicant`:

`wpasupplicant/xenial-security 2.4-0ubuntu6.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.4-0ubuntu6]`

But `wpa_supplicant -v` still simply says `v2.4`.